# How can I efficiently store a 2-way "like" system similar to Tinder?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

On Tinder, when 2 members like each other, they are a "match" and are able to communicate. If only one member likes another, then it's not a match.

I'm trying to store this "Like" system in MySQL but can't figure out the best way to do it that's efficient. This is my setup right now.

```
mysql> desc likes_likes;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from_user_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| to_user_id   | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| value        | int(11)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To find my matches, I would query something like...

```
SELECT to_user_id FROM likes_likes WHERE from_user_id = my_id AND value = 1 AND .... I don't know how to join the same table from here.
```

How do I perform the query on this table? If it's not efficient, what's a better structure to store this model?

1 is like, 0 is not like. Those are the only 2 values.

Comment: What is `value`? `1` for like, `-1` for hate? `0` for not like, `10` for adore?...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.from_user_id AS userA, B.from_user_id AS userB
FROM likes_likes A
JOIN likes_likes B
  ON A.from_user_id = B.to_user_id
  AND A.to_user_id = B.from_user_id
  AND A.id <> B.id
WHERE A.value = 1
  AND B.value = 1
```

Comment: Thank you.  What do I need to index for this to scale efficiently? The user_ids are already foreign keys, and I already have a unique on (from_user_id, to_user_id)

Comment: Actually, `(from_user_id, to_user_id)` is probably what I would go with, too.

Comment: What does the ```<>``` mean?

Comment: How do I check this for a certain user? For example, I want to get all matches where "from_user_id" is 5.

Comment: Where `>=` is "greater or equal", `<=` is "less or equal", by the same analogy `<>` is "greater or lesser", i.e. "not equal". In MySQL it is synonymous with `!=`, which has become standard lately; older programming languages tend to have `<>`. Check for a certain user: `... WHERE ... AND A.from_user_id = 5`.

Answer (score 1):

To find matches you can use a regular join with alias:

```
SELECT l1.from_user_id user1, l2.from_user_id user2
FROM likes_likes l1
INNER JOIN likes_likes l2 ON
  l2.from_user_id = l1.to_user_id AND
  l1.to_user_id = l2.from_user_id AND
  l1.value = 1 AND l2.value = 1
```

The first condition checks whether the person `user1` has liked or not liked `user2` and that `user2` has liked at least one other person.

The second condition completes the check so that we now have two persons who have expressed an opinion about each other.

The last two checks make sure that they both like each other :)

Comment: Thanks Jack. How do I check this for a certain user? For example, I want to get all matches where "from_user_id" is 5.

Comment: @TIMEX just put it in the WHERE clause

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `group by least(),greatest()` to get each unique pair of users into a group and then checking if there are 2 rows per group

```
select least(from_user_id,to_user_id), greatest(from_user_id,to_user_id)
from likes_likes
where value = 1
-- and my_id in (from_user_id,to_user_id)
group by least(from_user_id,to_user_id), greatest(from_user_id,to_user_id)
having count(*) = 2
```

If it's possible to have multiple likes from the same user to another user (i.e. user 'A' likes user 'B' twice) then use `having count(distinct from_user_id) = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need `value`? If there is no row there is no like. From this query you should get `1` for a match and `0` for no mutual match.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  likes_like i_like_you
 JOIN likes_like you_like_me ON i_like_you.to_user_id = you_like_me.from_user_id
WHERE 
  i_like_you.from_user_id = @my_id
  AND you_like_me.from_user_id = @your_id
```

Comment: I think you also need `and value = 1`

Comment: @Bohemian you can ignore value if you only add a row for a like. Using it would imply you will store all dislikes as well which means many many more rows. No presence of a like row can imply the dislike.

Comment: You need to keep track of who someone didn't like, otherwise they keep popping up :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason for `id`?  It seems like the pair (`from_user_id`, `to_user_id`) should be UNIQUE, hence could be the 'natural' `PRIMARY KEY`.

I have yet to see any good argument for needing `value`.

So the table has shrunk to

```
CREATE TABLE likes_likes (
    from_user_id ...,
    to_user_id ...,
    created_at ...,
    updated_at ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(from_user_id, to_user_id), -- serves as the necessary INDEX.
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

SELECT  A.from_user_id AS userA,
        B.from_user_id AS userB
    FROM  likes_likes A
    JOIN  likes_likes B
         ON  A.from_user_id = B.to_user_id
        AND  A.to_user_id = B.from_user_id
```

(I'm assuming you disallow a person liking himself.)

Comment: "I have yet to see any good argument for needing `value`": As said by @DaveAnderson below his answer, there are three situations: not judged (row absent), judged favourably (`value` is `1`) and judged unfavourably (`value` is `0`). Without `value`, you only have two possibilities: row missing or present. This makes it impossible to tell apart whether the user has already seen and dismissed the pairing, or it's a new pairing that was never presented to the user yet.